# Extend, but for objects instead of classes

Tags: javascript

In software, we usually use the word 'extends' to refer to the subclassing of a superclass, but is there good terminology to use when 'extending' the properties of an object instead of a class in a systematic way?

for example, in JavaScript, if I have an object like so:

```
var foo = {

property1:'',
property2:''

}
```

then I have:

```
var bar = {

property3:''

}
```

if I add bar's properties to foo's properties, this is what I mean.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). After your edit, I know that you are looking for prototyping because this is the extension mechanism in JavaScript.

Comment: `bar.constructor.prototype= Object.create(foo)` ??

Comment: @Alex Properties of object mens instance variable.

Comment: You cannot ask this question for both Java and JavaScript. JavaScript (before ES6, that is) doesn't even *have* classes; while Java does not support properties on objects that are not defined on a class. Make up your mind what you're asking about.

Comment: You should probably use only `JavaScript` in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the terminology `extend` has been adopted for adding the properties in one object to those in another. jQuery does this, but it probably wasn't the first. Underscore uses the same terminology:

```
_.extend(myObj, {newProp1: 1})
$.extend(myObj, {newProp1: 1})
```

Ember, on the other hand, uses `extend` in the subclassing sense, and the API for adding properties is `Ember.merge`.

The ES6 version is called `assign`:

```
Object.assign(myObj, {newProp1: 1})
```

There is no standard terminology and no standard way to differentiate the notions of extending an object with new properties and extending a class in the sense of subclassing it.

Answer (score 1):

You may call that merging or extending. You can "extend" an object with another with a function like this :

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    for(var key in obj2) {
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
}
```

PS. Prototypal inheritance is your friend.